# Why are custom dimensions sent on unrelated events in Google Analytics?

Tags: google-analytics

I have configured a few Custom Dimensions with google analytics and are reporting correctly where needed. However; some custom dimensions are being sent where they should not be sent.

Example:

I have an event that gets triggered after the login api responds with an error

```
  {
     action: 'Login Error',
     category: ''Login Page,
     errors: 'Invalid email or password',
  }
```

I have noticed on GA that the `errors` custom dimension is showing up in other events, with values from previous events.

I'm suspecting it is something that has to do with the event scope, but i'm not quite sure what scope it should be. `Errors` has a scope of `hit`

Answer (score 0):

If you want the custom dimension to be associated with an interaction its scope must be that of `hit`.